# Directory.getFiles An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I am relatively well versed in C#, having worked in Unity (game engine) for a good 5 years now, but don't go near Windows much, just a heads up if it's something stupid I've missed.

In my WPF application, I am trying to look for a file in the root application location (\bin\Debug), but I keep receiving this error when I run it.

> An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code Additional information: The directory
>   name is invalid.

Hopefully someone here can see what I've done wrong, and aid me in fixing this.
I am working on this as a side project for a friend who needed some help from someone who knows c#, but I've never gone near the Windows side of things before. (It's being run in the "public MainWindow()" initializer).

```
InitializeComponent();
string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "settings.txt");
string fileContent = filePath.ToString();
string[] contentArray = fileContent.Split(':');
string contentColor;
string contentIntensity;

for (int i = 0; i < contentArray.Length; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            if (contentArray[i].ToLower().Contains("color: "))
            {
                contentColor = contentArray[i].Replace("title: ", "");
            }

            if (contentArray[i].ToLower().Contains("intensity: "))
            {
                contentIntensity = contentArray[i].Replace("intensity: ", "");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call `Directory.GetFiles` with a directory. Example: `@"C:\Windows"`.

Answer (score 2):

What were you thinking here?

```
string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "settings.txt");
string fileContent = filePath.ToString();
```

It should be written as :

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "settings.txt");
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
 var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).
       Where(name => name.Contains("settings")).ToList();
```

or

```
 var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).
       Where(name => name.EndsWith(".txt")).ToList();
```

or return a string[]

```
 var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).
       Where(name => name.EndsWith(".txt")).ToArray();
```

Comment: `.Where` is not necessary here. You can pass a filter to `.GetFiles(path, searchPattern)` like `"setting.*"` or `"*.txt"`

Comment: @Xiaoy312 this is doing it using a lambda statement works just the same also what if you wanted to get a list of files with `.txt` extension.. the Contains would be the filter..

Comment: Yeah, but it's not necessary, the `GetFiles` method has an overload where you can pass in search patterns with wildcard characters. So your first example would be: `var settingsFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*settings*");`. Your second example: `var txtFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.txt");`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sure it almost does the same thing. I am to provide a shorter way of writing it. Regarding the 'settings' one, you may get some false positives if the application is stored in a directory containing "settings".

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Directory.GetFiles :**

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the
>   specified search pattern in the specified `directory`.

The method `GetFiles` accepts one or two parameters, a `path` or a `path and a search pattern`, the path has to be a `directory` !

**IOException** occurs when :

Path is a `file name` or there is a network error, and you are in the first case.
the method argument you are giving `(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "settings.txt")` which is a file name not a directory, that's why you are having that exception.

So, instead of calling GetFiles on a File !! Just combine the two strings to get a file path by doing :

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "settings.txt");
```